# How to manually increase spacing between two specific boxes within a grouped box plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouping, boxplot, spacing

Is there a way to increase the spacing between the yellow and red boxes within this box plot?

```
set.seed(40)
df <- data.frame(
  Outcome = runif(60), 
  Fruit = rep(1:3, each = 10), 
  Freshness = rep(c(0, 0.5), each = 30), 
  Farm = factor(rep(c("A", "B"), each = 5))
) %>% 
  transform(
  Outcome = Outcome*Fruit+Freshness, 
  Fruit = as.factor(Fruit), 
  Freshness = as.factor(Freshness)
)

ggplot(data = df, aes(Farm, Outcome, col = Freshness, fill = Fruit)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("lightslategrey", "black"), labels = c("Stale", "Fresh")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "orange", "yellow"), labels = c("Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas"))
```

[image]

I want to increase the spacing (or put a gap) between the "Freshness" color groups within each "Farm" group, but not so much that the boxes would be as separated as the "Farm" groups. That is, I only want to increase the spacing between yellow and red boxes to emphasize the difference between "Freshness" groups.

The "Fruit" groups would still maintain their distance between boxes within the group. That is, the neighboring red, orange, and yellow boxes will remain close together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a hack:

The following things were done:

- create new `Fruit` with values outside of range (negative, in this case)
- restrict ylim to positive values, as to prevent showing this new fruit in the plot
- fudge legend to not show this fruit (space still remains same, though)
- hide legend background to make this empty space in legend not show up

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(40)
df <- data.frame(
  Outcome = runif(60), 
  Fruit = rep(1:3, each = 10), 
  Freshness = rep(c(0, 0.5), each = 30), 
  Farm = factor(rep(c("A", "B"), each = 5))
) %>% 
  transform(
    Outcome = Outcome*Fruit+Freshness, 
    Fruit = as.factor(Fruit), 
    Freshness = as.factor(Freshness)
  )

dfe <- data.frame(
    Outcome = rep(-1,2), 
    Fruit = rep(" ", 2), 
    Freshness = c(0, 0),
    Farm=c("A", "B")
  )

df1 <- rbind(df, dfe) %>% 
  mutate(Fruit = factor(Fruit, levels=unique(Fruit)), 
         Freshness = factor(Freshness, levels=unique(Freshness)))

ggplot(data = df1, aes(Farm, Outcome, col = Freshness, fill = Fruit)) + 
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge2(padding=.1)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("lightslategrey", "black"), labels = c("Stale", "Fresh")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "orange", "yellow", "white"), labels = c("Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", ""))+
  scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE) + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,max(df1$Outcome)))+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = c(rep(.6, 3), 0), fill = c("red", "orange", "yellow", NA))))+
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the spacing between the boxes by adding `position=position_dodge(width =...))` to `geom_boxplot()` and playing around with the width selection until satisfied.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(Farm, Outcome, col = Freshness, fill = Fruit)) + 
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(width = 1)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("lightslategrey", "black"), labels = c("Stale", "Fresh")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "orange", "yellow"), labels = c("Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas"))
```

Here is the original for comparison.
[image]
And the modified (with `width=1`)
[image]
Increasing the spacing between the categories on the X axis is a different problem and a harder one to solve. One simple workaround is to use a facet with free scales on the X axis.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(Farm, Outcome, col = Freshness, fill = Fruit)) + 
    geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(width = 1)) + 
    scale_color_manual(values = c("lightslategrey", "black"), labels = c("Stale", "Fresh")) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "orange", "yellow"), labels = c("Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas")) +
    facet_wrap(~Farm, ncol = 2, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, the thing I want here, though, is that there is more of a gap between the yellow and the red boxes (because the gap would separate "Stale" and "Fresh" colored boxes more, further emphasizing that they're different groups).

Comment: That will require a fair of hacking in all likelihood. Rather than doing that, why not consider visually encoding that information using another dimension such as alpha, or using a more visible colour difference? You could also facet it both on freshness and farm, and make everything more clear at once.

Comment: I am curious about how to hack it, but thanks. Your suggestions are well taken.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to dshkol's answer, you can increase spacing between groups but it is somewhat of a hack.  First you need to create dummy data that falls between farm A and B (i.e. AA) and plot that. Because there is no data in the plot there won't be anything on the graph. Next, you need to specify your breaks as A and B so that the dummy AA does not show on the plot. You can adjust the spacing between boxplots by using the position_dodge argument and change the spacing between groups by adjusting the expand parameter. How close together the boxplots appear will also depend on what size image you export to.

```
# get unique values to set scale_x_discrete labels
farms <- unique(df$Farm)
dfmod <- df

# create dummy row with no data except for Farms
dfmod$Farm <- as.character(dfmod$Farm)
dfmod <- rbind(dfmod, list(NA, NA, NA, 'AA'))


ggplot(data = dfmod, aes(Farm, Outcome, col = Freshness, fill = Fruit)) + 
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(1)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("lightslategrey", "black"), labels = c("Stale", "Fresh")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "orange", "yellow"), labels = c("Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas")) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=farms, expand=c(0,2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the idea. However, my question probably was not clear. I want increase the gap only between yellow and red boxes within each "Farm" group. Your idea inspired an idea to add an invisible box between the yellow and red box (though it's not a perfect solution but can still work), but I haven't figured out how.