# add space and a line between two specified boxs in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a project using boxplots, but one of the boxplots was a little different from all others. So I want to add some more space between this box and all other, but in the meanwhile, the spacing between other boxes remain the same. And I also want to add a dash line between this box and all others.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = factor(gear), y = mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.5) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 4.5) + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

What I want is add some extra space between `factor(gear)` 4 and 5, while keeping the space between 3 and 4 the same. In addition, add a dash line between 4 and 5.

I tried to google this but did not find a good answer. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62013317/how-to-manually-increase-spacing-between-two-specific-boxes-within-a-grouped-box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make things more realistic, let's start off with `gear` as a factor rather than converting it inside ggplot:

```r
mtcars2 <- within(mtcars, gear <- factor(gear))
```

The trick is to make the discrete axis a continuous axis with custom labels. We therefore need to convert the factor to numeric and add a little to the rightmost value:

```
xvals <- as.numeric(mtcars2$gear)
xvals[xvals == max(xvals)] <- xvals[xvals == max(xvals)] + 1
mtcars2$xvals <- xvals
```

Now we plot using `xvals` on the x axis, but using the factor levels from `gear` to label the breaks. Note that we could use words instead of the characters "3", "4" and "5" even though this is a numeric axis.

```
ggplot(data = mtcars2, aes(x = xvals, y = mpg, group = gear)) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.5) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = max(xvals) - 1, linetype = 2) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = sort(unique(xvals)), labels = levels(mtcars2$gear)) +
  labs(x = "gear") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like we had the same idea. (;

Answer (score 3):

To manually add some additional space between boxplots we could add an additional factor level as shown in the post linked by @MrFlick in his comment. However, additionally you want to a seperating vertical without altering the spacing between the categories.

In my opinion the easiest way to achieve both is to convert the factor to numerics. Try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mtcars$gear <- factor(mtcars$gear)

# Save factor labels
labels <- levels(mtcars$gear)

mtcars %>%
  mutate(
    # Convert factor to numeric
    gear = as.numeric(gear),
    # Recode the special category, i.e. shift to the left. Here: Category 1
    gear = ifelse(gear == 1, 0.5, gear)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = gear, y = mpg, group = gear)) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.5) +
  # Add dahed line
  geom_vline(xintercept = 2.5, linetype = "dashed") +
  # Set breaks and labels
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0.5, 2:3), labels = labels) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]